# In Ruby (1.9.3), why does nil respond to the comparison operator, `<=>`?

Tags: ruby, null, comparable

To me, a null type being compared to anything else (even another null type) is an undefined operation.  Please correct me if I'm wrong there.

Under that assumption, the following makes sense to me:

```
nil.is_a? Comparable
 => false

nil.respond_to? :<=
 => false

nil.respond_to? :<
 => false

nil.respond_to? :>=
 => false

nil.respond_to? :>
 => false
```

However, `nil` *does* respond to the "spaceship" comparison operator:

```
nil.respond_to? :<=>
 => true
```

I cannot think of a situation where comparing `nil` is even meaningful, let alone practical.  Why does `nil` have this behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`nil` in Ruby is a singleton instance of `NilClass`, which inherits from `Object`. Object implements `<=>`, which has its behavior defined as:

> Returns 0 if obj and other are the same object or obj == other, otherwise nil. 0 means self is equal to other. 1 means self is bigger than other. Nil means the two values could not be compared.

(See [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E))

Thus, `nil <=> nil` returns 0 (they are equivalent), but `nil <=> anything_else` returns `nil`, which means "could not be compared".

In Ruby, it is expected that all objects respond to `<=>` (including `nil`), but for objects for which it is a nonsensical or undefined operation, the return value is `nil`, which may then be handled as the calling code best sees fit. In the case of Enumerable's operations like #sort, it raises an exception:

```
[1, nil].sort
# => ArgumentError: comparison of NilClass with 1 failed
```

But it needn't necessarily; you could implement your own sort which just moves unsortable values to the beginning of the list:

```
[1, nil, 2, 3, nil].sort {|a, b| (a <=> b) || -1 }
# => [nil, nil, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Well that explains the behaviour.  In your opinion, is there ever a situation where it's useful?  Or is this just one of those gotchas that any language has?

Comment: I think it's minimally useful; it exists so that if you have different opinions on how things should behave than Ruby does, you can implement those opinions, but I would agree that in most cases it is generally not useful.

Answer (score 1):

How useful is [Object#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) for `nil`? I think it's only limited by one's imagination.

**Example #1**

Here's a pedestrian example of how it can be useful. Suppose you wished to sort the array:

```
arr = [1,nil,3,nil,2]
```

with all the `nil`s coming first, so it would return:

```
[nil, nil, 1, 2, 3]
```

As:

```
nil<=>nil #=> 0
```

and, for all non-`nil` objects `a`:

```
nil<=>x   #=> nil
x<=>nil   #=> nil
```

we can write:

```
arr.sort { |a,b| (a<=>b) ? a<=>b : a.nil? ? -1 : 1 }
  #=> [nil, nil, 1, 2, 3]
```

**Example #2**

Now let's consider a second example that's much more interesting. Suppose we have oversold tickets to a theatre performance and must turn away some patrons, and give them refunds. The hash `tickets` shows what each person paid for their ticket:

```
ticket_holders = { 'bob'=>10, 'lucy'=>15, 'cher'=>5, 'arnold'=>12 }
```

We wish to minimize the refunds issued, but don't want negative publicity from turning away celebrities, given by the following:

```
celebrities = ['arnold', 'cher']
```

so we will give them the highest preference. We therefore wish to sort the `ticket_holders` by descending value, except we want key-value pairs whose key is in `celebrities` to come first. That is, we want the result to be:

```
['cher', 'arnold', 'lucy', 'bob']
```

or

```
['arnold', 'cher', 'lucy', 'bob']
```

Let's go for a general solution:

```
module Enumerable
  def sort_by_nils_first
    sort do |a,b|
      av = yield(a)
      bv = yield(b)
      (av<=>bv) ? av<=>bv : av.nil? ? -1 : 1
    end
  end
end
```

which we apply thus:

```
ticket_holders.sort_by_nils_first { |name,price|
  celebrities.include?(name) ? nil : -price }.map(&:first)
  #=> ["arnold", "cher", "lucy", "bob"]
```

Considering alone the number of celebrities in the world, and how they are treated, I think this is a pretty useful method.

Applied to the earlier example, we obtain:

```
[1,nil,3,nil,2].sort_by_nils_first(&:itself)
  #=> [nil, nil, 1, 2, 3]
```

where I've used [Object#itself](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Object.html#method-i-itself) from v2.2.

`sort_by_nils_first` could of course be modified to return an `Enumerator` when no block is given, to make it comparable to [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by).

Comment: Heh. I chose the exact example you did, before seeing your answer. Funny!

Comment: @ChrisHeald, yes, I noticed they appeared at the same time. I think my second example is more interesting, however.